# How to code for the eraser as like paint in android canvas?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-widget, android-canvas

In my drawing application, I am doing painting with on canvas with this code:

```
currentPaint = new Paint();
            currentPaint.setDither(true);
            currentPaint.setColor(0x00000000);
            currentPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            currentPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
            currentPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
            //currentPaint.setStrokeWidth(3);
```

No i want to implement the eraser as same as paint.
Is it possible to do it on canvas ? If yes then Please help me for it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create graphical objects with the color of the background. Then it looks like the things behind the objects are deleted.

Comment: I m not getting you properly. Is there any example that do like u said ?

Comment: Just set the color of the paint to the background color of your canvas. Then the painting will look like erasing.

Comment: Will you please put some code for it ? I dont know how to make it so.

Comment: Well Stackoverflow is not a website where people do your work. Sorry.

Answer (score 3):

```
  currentPaint.setAlpha(0xFF);
  currentPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
```

Call `invalidate` and the draw gets refreshed.

Answer (score 0):

use this code:

```
mPaint.setMaskFilter(null);
mPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
```